# Not able to load Microsoft.Http dll in ASP.NET MVC3 application at runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, httpclient

I created a WCF service and exposed it as REST service. I am trying to consume this service from ASP.Net MVC3 application.

I added a reference to Microsoft.Http dll, to use HttpClient and get the response from a POST method of REST service, as in the code below -

```
string uri = http://localhost:12958/Host1/RestService.svc/SubmitAdvisor;

using (HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpClient().Post(uri, HttpContentExtensions.CreateDataContract(obj)))

{

};
```

I get the follwing error at runtime -

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What is it I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Download from this link http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644
After,

Microsoft.Http.dll's location is like this

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF REST\WCF REST Starter Kit Preview
>   2\Assemblies